# How do I open three terminal tabs programmatically?

Tags: linux

I want to open three, or more, terminal tabs in my terminal.
I want to do this programmatically, from a shell script, or at the shell command line, rather than interactively via the terminal emulator's graphical user interface.

How do I do this?

Comment: Open a terminal in a terminal? It's unclear what you mean.

Comment: Completely unclear question. Please edit your question to formulate it better. Consider using an english <-> your native language dictionnary.

Comment: Still unclear question. If you are asking about opening a terminal on the command line, consider using `x-terminal-emulator` or `gnome-terminal` or `xterm` in your shell (perhaps followed by `&`). But do edit again your question to improve it. Give a paragraph of motivation.

Comment: Wild guess based on your poor input: You have one terminal window and want to control several shell sessions you can switch between via command line --> you are searching for [`screen`](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/).

Comment: Please try to explain a little clearer what you are trying to do. Are you trying to send data to multiple terminals ?

Comment: I'm open three terminal each terminal separately , I'm need open all terminal in a terminal only ( open tab ) by command line

Comment: See [How to run xfce-terminal with different commands per tab and keep using the tabs after the commands have returned?](/q/75902)

Answer (score 6):

It depends on your terminal.
While xterm can't do it, **gnome-terminal** can - and it comes built-in with Ubuntu.
Here's how you do it in gnome-terminal:

```
gnome-terminal --tab --tab --tab
```

You can even run commands in your tabs programmatically:

```
gnome-terminal  --tab -e "bash -c 'ps -ef; bash'" --tab -e "bash -c 'ls; bash'" --tab -e "bash -c 'top -n 1; bash'"
```

Note: if you don't add `bash` at the end of each command, the tab will be closed as soon the command completes. This is standard bash behavior and might be fine for long-running commands, e.g. ssh - but is quite annoying for the short ones when used inside tabs, presuming you want to keep using the tabs ;-)

P.S. I also found a way to do it on OS X for both Terminal and iTerm2, but there it requires Apple Script and is a bit more involved in general.

Answer (score 5):

Tab-enabled terminals generally have an option to open a terminal either as a new window or as a new tab. That's the case for example with `gnome-terminal` and `mate-terminal`.

On my Debian-like system, `x-terminal-emulator` is mapped to one of those via `update-alternatives`. This command would then allow me to open three tabs:

```
my_term=x-terminal-emulator
for i in 1 2 3; do "$my_term" --tab; done
```

Check the right option for your terminal and adapt this command.

Comment: `x-terminal-emulator` command not found

Comment: @abuali Then replace `x-terminal-emulator` with your terminal command

Comment: @abuali how exactly to implement this depends on what terminal emulator you are using... you haven't told us, so this is a great answer to a not so great question :)